# Selected Feature not highlighted in map of CMV (Configurable Map viewer)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I have copied the whole code of Find widget and added it into another widget. First widget is working fine and highlighting the feature(creating feature from geometry), second widget is also working fine. i.e. it is returning me the accurate and proper number of results, and same zoom extent but it is not drawing the feature, which are return by the query.

Answer (score 1):

Check your map service to ensure it is including the geometry in the response for the FindTask. You can do this by executing the FindTask via the REST API. If there is no geometry included in the response, most likely the "SHAPE" field was not included when the Map Service is published.

Comment: I am using same map services in my both find widgets.. Same queries too...v